# Retrieve data from third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, relation

This question is irritating to ask, as i haven't got the hang of using middle tables in sql yet. But i'm in a time rush so i've chosen to ask anyway.

I wish to combine these sql codes so i can retrieve the data from "teacher" aswell as "team" and "level", in the same repeater.

I'm catching a name from the "teacher" table through the FK_teacher from the middletable "teacher_team" which is related to my team table through FK_team

Would it by any chance be possible to combine these so i could extract it all through one repeater?

```
// Team <-> level relation

SELECT 
team.team_id as team_id,
level.level as level,
FROM team
INNER JOIN level ON level.level_id = team.team_FK_level
WHERE team.team_FK_type = @id


// Team <-> Team_Teacher <-> Teacher relation

SELECT teacher.teacher_name as name 
FROM teacher WHERE teacher.teacher_id 
IN (
SELECT teacher_team.FK_teacher
FROM teacher_team 
INNER JOIN team ON team.team_id = teacher_team.FK_team
WHERE team.team_FK_type = @id
)
```

*** EDIT ***
Got this code to work based on the answer of Ravi Singh. I've encountered another problem.
My repeater will output the teams row twice, if there are two teachers related to it in the teacher_teams (of course). Is there any way i could merge these without making a repeater inside a repeater?

```
SELECT 
team.team_id as team_id,
level.level as level,
teacher_team.FK_teacher,
teacher.teacher_name as teacher
FROM team
INNER JOIN level ON level.level_id = team.team_FK_level
LEFT JOIN teacher_team on teacher_team.FK_hold = team.team_id
LEFT JOIN teacheron teacher.teacher_id = teacher_team.FK_teacher
WHERE team.team_FK_type = @id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
teacher.teacher_name as name 
,team.team_id as team_id
,level.level as level
FROM teacher 
inner join teacher_team on teacher.teacher_id =teacher_team.FK_teacher
INNER JOIN team ON team.team_id = teacher_team.FK_team
INNER JOIN level ON level.level_id = team.team_FK_level
WHERE team.team_FK_type = @id
```

**Update :**
This should help with your updated question :

```
with demo_cte as(
SELECT 
teacher.teacher_name as name 
,team.team_id as team_id
,level.level as level
FROM teacher 
inner join teacher_team on teacher.teacher_id =teacher_team.FK_teacher
INNER JOIN team ON team.team_id = teacher_team.FK_team
INNER JOIN level ON level.level_id = team.team_FK_level
WHERE team.team_FK_type = @id
)


select distinct t1.team_id,
  t1.level, 
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + t2.name
          FROM demo_cte t2
          where t1.team_id = t2.team_id
            and t1.level = t2.level

          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS name
from demo_cte t1;
```

Comment: This isn't joining level.
my Team <-> Team_Teacher <-> Teacher relation does the same thing

Comment: I turned it around as team is my main table. 
But it worked yes =) I wasn't aware that i could grab every single table i wanted just by inner joining the middle table.

Comment: It's outputting the teams row twice in the repeater if there are more than 1 teacher_team row related to it. Any idea on how i can merge these without putting a repeater inside a repeater?

Comment: @GentlemenFinn : Do you want two teacher names to be in same row ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be done without a repeater in repeater, but yea that is basicly what i'm trying to accomplish.